# If Tradingview pro account expires, what will be the published protected script's type?

Tags: tradingview-api

I wrote a script and I want to hide its source code, so I need to upgrade my account to premium or pro account. I will buy 1 month plan, but after 1 month, what will be my script's sitiuation? Will it still be a protected script? Or will be a normal script?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it will change but if there is any chance it changes you should save your script somewhere so it is not affected.

Comment: no i mean after change everyone will see my script code so its not important to publish protected script.